# How translate python command to curl command

Tags: python, curl

I need to use the curl command instead of python code to call the api but it is not work .The python code is working with any problems but we want the command to be run as curl command

> `import requests
>     params = {'username': 'testuser'}
>     params['access_token'] = 'c3NhbmthMDJjsd'
>     params['region'] = 'test'
>     params['role'] = 'guide'
>     params['ipaddr'] = '192.168.0.37'
>     params['name'] = 'test-testhost-001'
>     params['check'] = 'enable' 
>     url = 'http://10.0.0.1:8000/monitor/'
>     r = requests.post(url, data=params)
>     r.json()`

I dont know how to run the above using the curl command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Heading ##Here's your python params put into raw post format  ... Good luck!

curl  \

-X POST \

-d "username=testuser&access_token=c3NhbmthMDJjsd&role=guide&name=test-testhost-001&check=check&region=test&ipaddr=192.168.0.37" \

http://10.0.0.1:8000/monitor/

Answer (score 1):

I wish this makes help you.

```
curl http://10.0.0.1:8000/monitor/ \
     -X POST \ 
     -F 'username=testuser' \
     -F 'access_token=c3NhbmthMDJjsd' \
     -F '<key>=<value>` | jq .
```

`jq` command is cli json processor.
Please see http://stedolan.github.io/jq/.